# Sort by multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am familiar with the basics of XSLT, but I've hit a weird situation I can't seem to figure out. I apologize for this being so long, but I would really appreciate any help you could provide.

I want to sort Level_5 node, based on the concatenation of the sorted Brand/Value/@Name and Docs/Value/@Name so yi sort Level_5

```
XML unsorted:
<Root att="x">
  <Level_1 Name="NEW Level">    
    <Level_2>      
      <Level_3 Name="nameLvl_3">        
        <Level_4>       
          <Level_5 Name="aa">
            <Brand>
              <Value Name="Text" Value="1" />
            </Brand>            
        <Docs>
              <Value Name="Pro" Value="2" />
              <Value Name="Numeric" Value="0.05" />
            </Docs>            
          </Level_5>              
          <Level_5 Name="aa">            
            <Text>
              <Val Id="1"/>
            </Text>
          </Level_5>
          <Level_5 Name="aa">
            <Brand>
              <Value Name="Text" Value="2" />
              <Value Name="Number" Value="1" />
              <Value Name="Long" Value="3" />
            </Brand>
          </Level_5>
        </Level_4>
      </Level_3>
    </Level_2>    
  </Level_1>
</Root>
```

After you do the concatenation you should have "", LongNumberText, TextNumericPro
and the Expected Output is:

```
<Root att="x">
  <level_1 Name="NEW Level">    
    <level_2>      
      <Level_3 Name="nameLvl_3">        
        <Level_4>
          <Level_5 Name="aa">            
            <Text>
              <Val Id="1"/>
            </Text>
          </Level_5>
          <Level_5 Name="aa">
            <Brand>
          <Value Name="Long" Value="3" />
      <Value Name="Number" Value="1" />
              <Value Name="Text" Value="2" />             
            </Brand>
          </Level_5>
          <Level_5 Name="aa">
            <Brand>
              <Value Name="Text" Value="1" />
            </Brand>            
    <Docs>          
              <Value Name="Numeric" Value="0.05" />
              <Value Name="Pro" Value="2" />
            </Docs>            
          </Level_5>
        </Level_4>
      </Level_3>
    </Level_2>    
  </Level_1>
</Root>
```

I can only sort by the first element of /Brand/Value/@Name but i don't have any idea how concatenate the rest of the attributes inside of Brand and Docs this is the code im uisng:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Level_3/Level_4/Level_5/Brand|Docs">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@Name" data-type="text"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@Value" data-type="text"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--                                                    -->
  <xsl:template match="Level_2/Level_3/Level_4">
    <xsl:copy>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Level_5">
        <xsl:sort select="Brand|Docs/Value/@Name" data-type="text"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i it just sort bye the first element inside of Brand or Docs please any help

Answer (score 0):

There may be a clever way to do this in an XPath 1.0 expression, but I'm not seeing one.  A more straightforward approach is to process the data in two steps.

First write a stylesheet that performs a near-identity transform:  the input is just written back to the output, as is, but on each Level_5 element you add an attribute with the sort-key, which you construct by processing all the appropriate children in a make-sort-key mode.

Then write the other stylesheet and use the sort-key attribute to control the sorting (and drop it again if you don't want it around).

On another topic:  the match pattern `Level_3/Level_4/Level_5/Brand | Docs` is not equivalent to `Level_3/Level_4/Level_5/Brand | Level_3/Level_4/Level_5/Docs`.  If it's the latter that you mean, you need a different match pattern.

Comment: I already do it by two steps but im restricted to do it in one step